# Code a validator for a WTForms form which compares the inputs from two fields

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I would like to have a validator which triggers a `ValidationException`, when the input for `feature_count` is smaller than for `effective_rank`.

I found information on this website (http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/64/) about wtforms validators, but do not know how to apply it to my problem.

Can you show me how it is done?

This is my code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, IntegerField, ValidationError
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, NumberRange, EqualTo,


class RequestDataForm(FlaskForm):
feature_count = IntegerField('Number of features', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=50)])

effective_rank = IntegerField('Effective Rank', validators=[DataRequired()])

noise = IntegerField('Noise', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=1)])

submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `Validator` called `EqualTo` which can be used to compare the equality of two fields. If you wanted `feature_count` to be the same as `effective_rank` you would simply need to add:

```
feature_count = IntegerField('Number of features', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('effective_rank'), NumberRange(min=1, max=50)])
```

However, in your specific case you want to ensure `LessThan` so the best solution I have is to copy and paste the code for the `EqualTo` class, rename it for your specific case, change the comparision and re-utilise it as a custom class:

```
class EqualTo(object):  # --> Change to 'LessThan'
    """
    Compares the values of two fields.

    :param fieldname:
        The name of the other field to compare to.
    :param message:
        Error message to raise in case of a validation error. Can be
        interpolated with `%(other_label)s` and `%(other_name)s` to provide a
        more helpful error.
    """
    def __init__(self, fieldname, message=None):
        self.fieldname = fieldname
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        try:
            other = form[self.fieldname]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValidationError(field.gettext("Invalid field name '%s'.") % self.fieldname)
        if field.data != other.data:  #  --> Change to >= from !=
            d = {
                'other_label': hasattr(other, 'label') and other.label.text or self.fieldname,
                'other_name': self.fieldname
            }
            message = self.message
            if message is None:
                message = field.gettext('Field must be equal to %(other_name)s.')

            raise ValidationError(message % d)
```

Then you can use:

```
feature_count = IntegerField('Number of features', validators=[DataRequired(), LessThan('effective_rank'), NumberRange(min=1, max=50)])
```