# For some FlaskForm validators, error message does not pop up

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

While "DataRequired" and "NumberRange" produce a pop-up error message, "EqualTo" (and my own custom "MoreThan") do not. How can I get them to also produce a pop-up message?

####################################################################
My form has three fields. "min_nFeatures" has to be lower than "max_nFeatures", so I changed the code of the "EqualTo" validator to "MoreThan" (as advised in [Code a validator for a WTForms form which compares the inputs from two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517418/code-a-validator-for-a-wtforms-form-which-compares-the-inputs-from-two-fields)). The validator is working: if the user enters a larger value for "min_nFeatures", it does not go through (it returns to the same page). However, there is no pop-up message as with the other built-in validators (for example, if the user does not enter anything, there's a pop-up "Please fill out this field"). I would like the same behavior for the custom validator.

My code:

```
class MoreThan(object):   

    def __init__(self, fieldname, message=None):
        self.fieldname = fieldname
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        try:
            other = form[self.fieldname]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValidationError(field.gettext("Invalid field name '%s'.") % self.fieldname)
        if field.data <= other.data:
            d = {
                'other_label': hasattr(other, 'label') and other.label.text or self.fieldname,
                'other_name': self.fieldname
            }
            message = self.message
            if message is None:
                message = field.gettext(
                    'The maximal number of expressed genes has to be larger than the minimal number of expressed genes')

            raise ValidationError(message)


class vln_plot_form(FlaskForm):
    min_nFeatures = IntegerField('* Minimal number of expressed genes:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    max_nFeatures = IntegerField('* Maximal number of expressed genes:',
                                 validators=[DataRequired(), MoreThan('min_nFeatures')])
    max_mtpercent = IntegerField('Maximal percent of mitochondrial gene expression:', validators=[NumberRange(1, 100)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

view:

```
@app.route('/vln', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def violin_plots():
    ...
    form = vln_plot_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            ...
            return redirect(url_for('next_page'))

    return render_template('violin_plots.html', form=form)
```

I read [Message not flashing on some WTForm validation methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061364/message-not-flashing-on-some-wtform-validation-methods) but could not apply it to my case.

########################################################################
edit:
Here's my HTML code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
<title>HELLO</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<center><h1>Run!</h1></center>
<h2>Step 2/3</h2>
<figure>
    <img src={{ vln_plot_file }} align="middle" alt="vln_plot" style="width:70%">
</figure>

<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            <label for=""> {{ form.min_nFeatures.label }}</label>
            {{ form.min_nFeatures }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            <label for=""> {{ form.max_nFeatures.label }}</label>
            {{ form.max_nFeatures }}
        </div>

        {% if with_mt %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            <label for=""> {{ form.max_mtpercent.label }}</label>
            {{ form.max_mtpercent }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {% endif %}
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Since I added "{{ form.errors }}" at the end of the HTML, I do see the correct form.errors at the bottom of the webpage, but this is of course a very ugly way to display the errors...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            <label for=""> {{ form.min_nFeatures.label }}</label>
            {{ form.min_nFeatures }}
            {% for error in form.min_nFeatures.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            <label for=""> {{ form.max_nFeatures.label }}</label>
            {{ form.max_nFeatures }}
            {% for error in form.max_nFeatures.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        {% if with_mt %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            <label for=""> {{ form.max_mtpercent.label }}</label>
            {{ form.max_mtpercent }}
            {% for error in form.max_mtpercent.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
        </div>
    </div>
</form
```

Note how I manage the display of errors for each of the fields individually.

Comment: Thanks! It is much better than what I had before... However- is there no way to make the error message pop up like with the built-in validators?

Comment: I can't figure out why it works differently, the custom validator MoreThan (or the original EqualTo) raises ValidationError the same as DataRequired and NumberRange, so why the message doesn't pop up in MoreThan and EqualTo as it does in DataRequired and NumberRange?